# Android studio: Error on sending Variable to Mysql after Toast

Tags: android, mysql

Hello I am new to Android, but reading as much as possible;

I create an APP for entering Trip Reports from Trucking.  I have the form corrected, but using VAL1-VAL2, then trying to send that using "registerAPI" is giving me failures.

So created RegisterAPI class of

```
public interface RegisterAPI {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/insert.php")
    public void insertUser(
            @Field("trucksID") String trucksID,
            @Field("tripReportNumber") String tripReportNumber,
            @Field("enteredDate") String enteredDate,
            @Field("emptyMilage") String emptyMilage,
            @Field("loadedMilage") String loadedMilage,
            @Field("estTotal") String estTotal,
            Callback<Response> callback);
```

Then in the MainActivity:

//Class for our main activity with OnClickListener
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
//Declaring views
private WebView webView;
private EditText trucksID;
private EditText tripReportNumber;
private EditText enteredDate;
private EditText emptyMilage;
private EditText loadedMilage;

private Button buttonRegister;
private String estTotal;
private String estMilage;

//This is our root url
public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://hosturl/php/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing Views
    trucksID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.trucksID);
    tripReportNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tripReportNumber);
    enteredDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enteredDate);
    emptyMilage= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emptyMilage);
    loadedMilage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loadedMilage);

    buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

    //Adding listener to button
    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
}




public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.openWebsite:
            Intent website = new Intent(this,ourWebsite.class);
            this.startActivity(website);
            return true;

        case R.id.goto2:
            Intent activity2 = new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
            this.startActivity(activity2);
            return true;

        case R.id.about_us:
            Intent about = new Intent(this,aboutUs.class);
            this.startActivity(about);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


private void insertUser(){
    //Here we will handle the http request to insert user to mysql db
    //Creating a RestAdapter
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
            .build(); //Finally building the adapter

    //Creating object for our interface
    RegisterAPI api = adapter.create(RegisterAPI.class);

    //Defining the method insertuser of our interface
    api.insertUser(

            //Passing the values by getting it from editTexts
            trucksID.getText().toString(),
            tripReportNumber.getText().toString(),
            enteredDate.getText().toString(),
            emptyMilage.getText().toString(),
            loadedMilage.getText().toString(),
            //can take this out below
            estTotal,

            //Creating an anonymous callback
            new Callback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                    //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                    //Creating a bufferedreader object
                    BufferedReader reader = null;

                    //An string to store output from the server
                    String output = "";

                    try {
                        //Initializing buffered reader
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

                        //Reading the output in the string
                        output = reader.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Displaying the output as a toast
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    //If any error occured displaying the error as toast
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

//Overriding onclick method
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Calling insertUser on button click
    insertUser();
    int value1=Integer.parseInt(emptyMilage.getText().toString());
    int value2=Integer.parseInt(loadedMilage.getText().toString());

    int estMilage=value2-value1;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Estimated Milage:"+String.valueOf(estMilage), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}
Here is the activity_main.xml i am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/logoview"
        android:src="@mipmap/platelogo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/atrixlogo"
        android:maxHeight="55dp"
        android:minHeight="55dp"
        android:minWidth="55dp"
        android:maxWidth="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Truck ID:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trucksID"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Trip Report Number:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tripReportNumber"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Trip Date:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enteredDate"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="MM/DD/YY" />



    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Empty Milage:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emptyMilage"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Loaded Milage:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loadedMilage"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
        android:text="Submit Trip Report"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But all i am seeing is the Toast, not carrying forward and inserting the estTotal into the Database onClick

When I run message:

```
    Error:(112, 25) error: cannot find symbol method getText()
Error:(102, 12) error: method insertUser in interface RegisterAPI cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String,String,String,String,String,Callback<Response>
found: String,String,String,String,String,<anonymous Callback<Response>>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

If i take out the  estTotal.gettext from the Mainactivity and RegisterAPI no errors on running.

I have been looking at a lot of the StackOverflow's but most of those are on one intent or one activity. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: `estTotal.getText().toString()` - because you are trying to call method `getText()` on `estTotal` - **but** `estTotal` is type `String`, not `EditText` or `TextView` - this is how you declared it `private String estTotal;`.
So removing the line `estTotal.getText().toString()` should solve the problem. What are you using `estTotal` for anyway?

I hope this helps.

Comment: He wants the form to <calculate the Loaded Mileage - the Empty mileage> and then submit that for the Mysql database.  

So the three columns are for <Empty / loaded / Difference>

Comment: But exactly where do you set the value for `estTotal` in your code? Please show your layout XML where you have `trucksID`, and others?

Comment: I updated all of the code, I took your suggestion on the Private String, that resolved the error, but Value still isnt passing to the db, only the toast.

Comment: I am using standard PHP
  //Getting post data 
  $trucksID = $_POST['trucksID'];
  $tripReportNumber = $_POST['tripReportNumber'];
  $enteredDate = $_POST['enteredDate'];
  $emptyMilage = $_POST['emptyMilage'];
  $loadedMilage = $_POST['loadedMilage'];
  $estTotal = $_POST['estTotal'];

Comment: also:
I added the two strings together at the bottom of the code in the onClick Method, it was how i showed the toast:

Comment: Hi, thanks for the updates - in order to manage the scope of your question, if you say "I took your suggestion on the Private String, that resolved the error" - then don't you want accept this answer AND then to post a related question specifically for the problem where value is not passing to the database? You can paste the link to that question on the comments here - this will enable others to also jump in and help.